# Adding config in PreBid Server (hosted by AppNexus)

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I would like to use the PreBid Mobile SDK with PreBid Server:
http://prebid.org/dev-docs/get-started-with-prebid-server.html

I'm configuring a PreBid Server account hosted by AppNexus,
but I do not know how to add a server-side bidder configuration here:  https://prebid.adnxs.com/configs/

I would like help on the format when I choose to add a new config.